# Why adding the first verse to Ashrei Yoshvei Beitecha

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms

The Mizmor Ashrei Yoshvei Beitecha is mostly based on the 145 chapter in Psalms. The first two verses begin in the 84:5 chapter and the last verse of the 144 chapter. It is understood that apparently the authors of the Mizmor wanted to start with the letter Aleph and therefore needed to add the last verse of the previous 184 chapter. And the question is why is the verse of chapter 84 also required? Why weren't they satisfied with last verse of 144 Chapter? Why is it required to seemingly duplicate the verse that begins with the letter Aleph and why exactly was the verse in the 84:5 chapter chosen for this?

Comment: Why is it understood that they want to start with alef?

Comment: **[רא"ש ברכות א ו](https://www.responsa.co.il/wiki.aspx?docId=0301500000000000000600000000)**:

אמר ר' אלעזר כל האומר תהלה לדוד בכל יום מובטח לו שהוא בן העולם הבא. מה שאנו פותחין באשרי יושבי משום דמניה נפקא לן לקמן (דף לב ב) צריך אדם שישהה שעה אחת קודם שיתפלל. וגם מסיימין ואנחנו נברך יה כדי שיסיים בהללויה.

Comment: See this [relevant answer on a different question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10124/7539)

Comment: Thanks @Rish, but there are 2 questions: why is the one hour applies only to Ashrei Mizmor? And is adding only one verse is equal to one hour reading? It could be relavant for instance to adding several verses at the beginning of Psukei DeZimra (such as before Hodu or Baruch Sheamar)?